# Liken Vs Compare to / with

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, word-meaning, sentence-meaning, difference

I know that:

1. Liken - to find similarities.
2. Compare - to find similarities and differences.

Also, as far as I am concerned, the use of the preposition "with" along with the verb "compare" is a comparison between two similar things, whereas, "to" is used when we are comparing two very different objects / people.

That being said, I have no idea how the following sentences differ in meaning:

- He **likened** her eyes **to** the depth of the oceans.
- He **compared** her eyes **to** the depth of the oceans.
- He **compared** her eyes **with** the depth of the oceans.

Comment: There's no meaningful ***semantic*** difference. By far the dominant factor is simply that [***liken*** is very rare compared to ***compare***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=compared+her+face+to%2Clikened+her+face+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3). Plus there's a little bit of "syntactic" difference in that *"liken" is very rare **likened** to "compare"* isn't remotely idiomatic (but I'd still say it's "grammatically valid").

Comment: The final example is relatively "unusual" today. [Increasingly over recent decades](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=when+compared+to%2Cwhen+compared+with&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) we've switched from comparing X ***with*** Y to comparing X ***to*** Y.

Comment: Hence, you are probably rejecting the idea that: the use of the preposition "**with**" along with the verb "compare" is a comparison between two **similar things / people**, whereas, "**to**" is used when we are comparing two **very different objects / people.** Right @FumbleFingers?

Comment: I'm not necessarily saying that usage distinction doesn't exist at all. But my linked chart clearly shows a significant shift in usage over time, and it's obviously nonsense to suggest that over the past century Anglophones have significantly shifted from comparing *similarities* between X and Y to comparing *differences* between them.

Comment: Also, did you mean by: "By far the dominant factor is simply that liken is very rare compared to compare." that **the verb "liken" is considered a very rare word in this specific sense** (I mean comparing the similarities between X and Y,) and the verb "compare has been replaced with it? And finally, do you mean that **"liken" is not used in passive form** by saying: "liken" is very rare likened to "compare" isn't remotely idiomatic"? @FumbleFingers

Comment: May I ask you @FumbleFingers which preposition is correct in the following sentence? "People used to compare his voice **to / with** Bolton's voice."

Comment: As implied by the usage shift reflected in my previous link, you can't just pick a date and say *"**for**" is the correct preposition from this date onwards*. The vast majority of native speakers *today* would compare his voice ***to*** [something they thought sounded similar], but that doesn't make ***with*** "incorrect" - just "less likely". There's an increasing *tendency* to use ***to*** when "likening", and ***with*** when "contrasting" - but that's just a tendency, nowhere near an absolute rule.

Comment: If you're not sure how to use ***liken***, just do the same as the vast majority of native Anglophones. Don't use it at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139311/discussion-between-a-friend-and-fumblefingers).

Comment: Would you answer to this question please @FumbleFingers? It would be definitely my intended response and I can accept.

Comment: I don't think I have anything to add to @gotube's answer. The primary message should be *Forget about "liken", which  native speakers rarely use anyway*. The secondary point (that *some* people in *some* contexts will assume ***compare*** means either ***liken*** or ***contrast*** depending on whether it's followed by ***to*** or ***with***) is already *perfectly* "caveated" by the mere fact that gotube and I have different ideas about which preposition goes with which meaning. I wouldn't want to disturb such a carefully balanced perspective! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A big difference between "liken" and "compare" is that "liken" is so uncommon, that it's mostly used poetically. So, of your example sentences, the one with "liken" sounds like dripping romantic poetry, while the other two *could* have romantic feelings behind them, or they could be straightforward statements describing what some guy did.

The difference between "*compare to*" and "*compare with*" is that generally we use "*compare with*" in the same sense as "liken", meaning to declare that there are similarities, and we use "*compare to*" to make a comparison, maybe to find whether there are any similarities or differences.

So, in a romantic statement, "*He compared her eyes **with** the depth of the oceans*" is more likely, because it usually means the two are similar. But after I hear, "*He compared her eyes **to** the depth of the oceans*, I want to know the results. What did he find? Which was deeper? Were they similar?

To be clear, this difference between "compare with" and "compare to" is *not a grammar rule*. Both "with" and "to" can be used to mean "liken" and to mean "find similarities and differences". The choice between the two is a *preference* among English speakers and is only about semantics.

Comment: So you mean that there is nothing particular in terms of register to be considered by a non-native speaker while it is a matter of semantics which can be preferred only by native speakers. Is that right @gotube?

Comment: @A-friend What do you mean by "register"? can you give examples? Also, I didn't say "native speakers". I said, "English speakers", which includes non-native speakers.

Comment: I guess there are some conflicts between your and @Fumblefingers explanations here. If so, then is it a matter of regional dissimilarities?

Comment: What @A-friend said! I don't think it's a very *strong* tendency, but I definitely think that *on average* people use *compare **to*** when "likening, equating", and *compare **with*** when "evaluating, contrasting". But the key point here is that if two linguistically competent native Anglophones can take opposite positions re that distinction, it *can't* be very consistently observed. I saw no significant difference in the usage shift over time as reflected by NGrams with AmE / BrE corpuses, and I seriously doubt there's any meaningful lower-level dialectal division.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Isn't that interesting! At least we were both clear that this isn't a strong rule.

Comment: English abhors a synonym just as much as Nature abhors a vacuum! ***If*** there are two difference ways of saying the same thing, pretty soon people start assigning different meanings. That often means whichever phrasing was or becomes more often used gets assigned the most common meaning, and the alternative phrasing gets the next most likely candidate sense. But it takes decades for that  process to settle down, so in the meantime there are bound to be different perspectives. Me, I start with Shakespeare's obviously "liken" usage: *Shall I compare thee **to** a summer's day?*

Comment: @FumbleFingers "*English abhors a synonym*". Truer words.